# How to get the Google account ID from a Google+ vanity URL

Tags: google-plus, google-account, vanity-url, google-people-api

Google+ API did shut down.
Google People API can be used instead, using the same account IDs.
However, People API does not accept names from Google+ vanity URLs.
How can I get the account ID from a Google+ vanity URL, now that I can't use Google+ API for this task anymore?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get
- On the right-hand side in the Try this API section, in "userId" enter "me"
- Press the Execute button
- If not already logged in log in with your Google account
- After a successful login, an HTTP 200 result is shown
- Below an "id" entry is shown

[source](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/134153)

Comment: Thank you, but it is not about me. I like to get the ID for any old Google+ vanity URL.